# google charts : table chart - get values from object-literal notation datasource

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, event-listener

Considering the below data source and Listener function.

**Data Source**

```
 var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(
                    {
                        cols: [{ type: 'string', label: 'Col1' }, 
                               { type: 'number', label: 'col2' }, 
                               { type: 'boolean', label: 'MyBoolean' }],
                        rows: [
                            { c: [{ v: 'data1' }, { v: 1 }, {v: false}] },
                            { c: [{ v: 'data2' }, { v: 2 }, {v:true}] }
                        ]
                    });
```

**Listener Function :**

```
 function ChartSelect()
            {
                var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
                console.log(dataSource.getValue(selectedItem.row, 1));
            }
```

I know below line will throw error

```
console.log(dataSource.getValue(selectedItem.row, 1));
```

Considering i clicked on first row, how can i read the second element of the datasource (i.e '1')?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Got it, Its nothing more than fetching values from java script objects in object-literal-notation.

```
var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0]; // considering user clicked on first row
data["rows"][selectedItem.row]["c"][1]["v"] // will do the trick.
```